# How to mix compile HIP and Fortran using CMake

Tags: cmake, fortran, linker-errors

I don't know how to mix HIP compilation and Fortran using CMake. The follow is a demo.

I have 3 files:

- fcode.f90

```
SUBROUTINE fcode()
      implicit double precision (a-h, o-z)
      parameter (M=64)
      dimension x(M),y(M),z(M)
      do k=1, M
           x(k) = 1.0
           y(k) = 2.0
           z(k) = 0.0
      end do  
      call hipcode(x,y,z,M)
      do k = 1, M
         if ( z(k) .ne. 3.0 ) then
           write(6,*) 'u fail !'
           return
         endif
      end do
      write(6,*)' PASSED !'
      return
end
```

- hipcode.cpp

```cpp
#include <hip/hip_runtime.h>

#define HIP_ASSERT(status) assert(status == hipSuccess)

__global__ void add(double *x, double *y, double *z, const unsigned int M) {
  z[threadIdx.x] = x[threadIdx.x] + y[threadIdx.x];
}

extern "C" void hipcode_(double *h_x, double *h_y, double *h_z, int &M) {

  HIP_ASSERT(hipSetDevice(0));

  double *d_x, *d_y, *d_z;
  HIP_ASSERT(hipMalloc((void **)&d_x, M * sizeof(double)));
  HIP_ASSERT(hipMalloc((void **)&d_y, M * sizeof(double)));
  HIP_ASSERT(hipMalloc((void **)&d_z, M * sizeof(double)));

  HIP_ASSERT(hipMemcpy(d_x, h_x, M * sizeof(double), hipMemcpyHostToDevice));
  HIP_ASSERT(hipMemcpy(d_y, h_y, M * sizeof(double), hipMemcpyHostToDevice));
  HIP_ASSERT(hipMemcpy(d_z, h_z, M * sizeof(double), hipMemcpyHostToDevice));

  hipLaunchKernelGGL(add, 1, 64, 0, 0, d_x, d_y, d_z, M);
  HIP_ASSERT(hipMemcpy(h_z, d_z, M * sizeof(double), hipMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  hipFree(d_x);
  hipFree(d_y);
  hipFree(d_z);
}
```

- main.f90

```
call fcode()
    stop
end
```

and I write a Makefile to compile it, it works. But I don't know how to use cmake to do this.

```
OBJS=main.o fcode.o hipcode.o
FC=gfortran
HIPCC=hipcc
FCFLAGS=-c
HIPCCFLAGS=-c
LDFLAGS=-lgfortran
all :
        $(HIPCC) $(HIPCCFLAGS) hipcode.cpp
        $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) fcode.f90
        $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) main.f90
        $(HIPCC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o test
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(test LANGUAGES Fortran CXX)

# source file: hipcode.cpp fcode.f90 main.f90
# target:
# hipcc -c hipcode.cpp
# gfortran -c fcode.f90
# gfortran -c main.f90
# hipcc hipcode.o fcode.o main.o -lgfortran -o test

set(sources_list hipcode.cpp)
set(raw_sources_list_f90 fcode.f90)

# find hip
find_package(HIP QUIET)

set(CMAKE_HIP_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__HIP_PLATFORM_HCC__  --offload-arch=gfx906")
set(HIP_CLANG_FLAGS "${HIP_CLANG_FLAG} --hip-link")

set_source_files_properties(${sources_list} PROPERTIES HIP_SOURCE_PROPERTY_FORMAT 1)
set(MY_SOURCE_FILES ${sources_list})
set(MY_TARGET_NAME hipcode)
set(MY_HIPCC_OPTIONS "--hip-link")
set(HIP_TARGET_LINK_LIB "rocm/hip/lib/libamdhip64.so" )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -x hip -fgpu-rdc --hip-link  -std=c++14 -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "hipcc")
set(CMAKE_HIP_FLAFS "${CMAKE_HIP_FLAGS} --hip-link")
set(CMAKE_HIP_LINKER_WRAPPER_FLAG "--hip-link")
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS    "  -fgpu-rdc --hip-link  -std=c++14 ")
set(HIP_HIPCC_CMAKE_LINKER_HELPER "hipcc")
set(HIP_CLANG_PATH   " ")
set(HIP_CLANG_PARALLEL_BUILD_LINK_OPTIONS " ")
add_library(${MY_TARGET_NAME} ${MY_SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${MY_TARGET_NAME}  ${HIP_TARGET_LINK_LIB} )

add_library(fcodef90 STATIC ${raw_sources_list_f90})
target_link_libraries(fcodef90 hipcode)
```

I use `CXX=hipcc cmake .. && make -j` to build the demo, and it passed.

[image]

But then I got an error: "undefined reference to `hipcode_'", so how to modify the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Looks like you need `ISO_C_BINDING`. See also the tag `[fortran-iso-c-binding]` (e.g as starting point https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran-iso-c-binding/info

Comment: Also help yourself and at the very least use `Implicit None`. Also your constants aren't the same precision as your variables.

Comment: The Fortran code is indeed ugly, but the error comes because the `hipcc` does not get the hipcode_() function from hipcode.cpp. I do not know how to add it into that command, I do not use CMake. It is really discouraged to use images for error messages. Fortunately, you copied at least the very message as text, but normally you should present the whole output and all the commands as text. See [ask].

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the picture. Does it actually come from a `cmake` or `make` command? Why are there separate `gfortran` and `hipcc` commands on separate command lines? t looks like you executed them manually.

Comment: sorry, this is my first time to ask a question using stack overflow. I'll take care of that later. I have a lot of `.c` code and I want to compile them into a static library. Besides, I hope the funtions can be used in the Fortran, so I also want to get a `.mod` file. Here I use `add_library(fcodef90 STATIC ${raw_sources_list_f90})
` compile Fortran interface and use `target_link_libraries(fcodef90 hipcode)` link the C static library. I don't know if I made it clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As suggested in my initial comment the problem lies probably on the Fortran side and has nothing to do with cmake. Best is to see which symbols are defined / required in the `libfcodef90.a`  and are defined / required in the `main.o` by means of the `nm` command especially in relation to the `hipcode_` symbol.

Comment: @AoShen Please clarify, does the picture actually show the `make` output or did you execute the commands manually? What exactly did you execute?

Comment: @albert I suspicion is exactly opposite.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава do you mean on the CMake side or on the Cpp side (as in the cpp code I see: `extern "C" void hipcode_(...` and this looks to me like a clear indication of a name mangling problem).

Comment: @albert The CMake side. I think this manual mangling normally works in practice in for the defaults of common compilers. Jest tested that for gfortran/g++ and icc/ifort.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава it might work but it would be better to see what result of the `nm` command to be on the safe side. It might be that some special options have to be set for the, to me, unknown `hipcc` compiler (probably a wrapper around a "standard" compiler)

Comment: I agree, we have too many unkowns. The diagnosis requires smaller steps.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава The picture is the output of compile the final executable file.By using CMake, I got `ibhipcode.a`(which can be used in C) and `libfcodef90.a`(I hope it can be used in Fortran), then I use gfortran to compile `main.f90`, next use hipcc to compile and link them, the result is the output of the last step.

Comment: As mentioned a couple of times above, “nm” is your friend here. You could use ISO_C_BINDING and the BIND argument to remove the trailing underscore (or using the train gun der score on the C call. Then you are likely either making the Fortran side work on the stack and passing by value, or on the C-side passing by reference. The later is what was done before ISO_C_BINDING and it works still. Either way is OK if it works. It just needs to be reference to reference, or value to value, and the C need to see the symbol in the library or .o and hence “nm”.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you again, after use `nm`, I realized that maybe I need to add separate compilation options, [then I found answer here](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP/issues/2203), all right, thank you very much!

And the final compiled command is

```
gfortran -c main.f90
hipcc -fgpu-rdc --hip-link main.o libfcode.a libhipcode.a -lgfortran
```